# Is it true? Does PostgreSQL LIMIT throw away all other instances?

Tags: postgresql

I've been looking for a straight clean answer to the this question. Let's say I have a photo table.

Now this table has 1,000,000 rows. Let's do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY creation_time LIMIT 10;
```

Will this query grab all 1,000,000 rows and then give me 10? or does it just grab the latest 10? I'm quite curious as to how this works because if it does grab 1,000,000 (mind you this table is constantly growing) then it's wasteful query. You're basically throwing away 999,980 rows away. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Basically, yes. There is no other way. Postgres **has** to first sort **all** the rows based on `creation_time` to be able to find the latest 10 (Although it won't "grab" them). But it might as well use an index for that, but only the execution plan can tell.

Comment: Here is an execution plan doing something like your query on a table with 4.7 million rows: http://explain.depesz.com/s/FxM

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks a lot! Hmm, usually my queries are more refined where I filter by the photo_author. I was thinking storing the id's of the photos that belong to AuthorA into a redis list. And then do a select from the photo table for those IDS.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what do you think?

Comment: @harmic explains it well - the answer is "sometimes, yes". Proper table and query design helps. You should avoid using `offset` even more than `limit` since its *purpose* is to generate and throw away rows. Where possible try to use range queries on IDs or other keys instead, since these are more likely to be able to efficiently use indexes. None of this is specific to PostgreSQL, it's true of most (all?) RDBMSes to one extent or another.

Comment: This problem (?) is there with most databases.I have had to optimize a query in Oracle where we had to fetch the latest 10 activities for frequent flyer/loyalty program, to be displayed when the user logs in. Ordering by on activity date for a table where no record could be 'purged' takes time. You could look at flagging really old data as Expired, apply a filter on that and reduce the number of records fetched for the Order By

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether the database has to scan the whole table or not depends on a number of
factors - in the case you describe the main factors are whether there is an ORDER BY 
clause and whether there is an index on the sort field(s).

All is revealed by looking at the query plan, and the cost approximations on each
of the operations. Consider the case where there is no ordering clause:

```
testdb=> explain select * from bigtable limit 10;
                                QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..0.22 rows=10 width=39)
   ->  Seq Scan on bigtable  (cost=0.00..6943.06 rows=314406 width=39)
(2 rows)
```

The planner has decided that a sequential scan is the way to go. The expected cost
already gives us a clue. It is expressed as a range, 0.00..6943.06. The first number
(0.00) is the amount of work the database expects to have to do before it can deliver
any rows, while the second number is an estimate of the work required to deliver
the whole scan.

Thus, the input to the 'Limit' clause is going to start straight away, and it will
not have to process the full output of the sequential scan (since the total cost
is only 0.22, not 6943.06). So it definitely will not have to read the whole table
and discard most of it.

Now lets see what happens if you add an ORDER BY clause, using a column that is not
indexed.

```
testdb=> explain select * from bigtable ORDER BY title limit 10;
                                   QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=13737.26..13737.29 rows=10 width=39)
   ->  Sort  (cost=13737.26..14523.28 rows=314406 width=39)
         Sort Key: title
         ->  Seq Scan on bigtable  (cost=0.00..6943.06 rows=314406 width=39)
(4 rows)
```

We have a similar plan, but there is a 'Sort' operation in between the seq scan
and the limit. It has to scan the complete table, sort the full content of it,
and only then can is start delivering rows to the Limit clause. It makes sense
when you think about it - LIMIT is supposed to apply after ORDER BY; so it would
have to be sure to have found the top 10 rows in the whole table.

Now what happens when an index is used? Suppose we have a 'time' column which is
indexed:

```
testdb=> explain select * from bigtable ORDER BY time limit 10;
                                                QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..0.35 rows=10 width=39)
   ->  Index Scan using bigtable_time_idx on bigtable  (cost=0.00..10854.96 rows=314406 width=39)
(2 rows)
```

An index scan, using the time index, is able to start delivering rows in already
sorted order (cost starts at 0.00). The LIMIT can cut the query short after
only 10 rows, so the overall cost is very small.

The moral to the story is to carefully choose which columns or combinations of
columns you will index. You can't add them indiscriminately because adding an
index has a cost of its own - it makes it more expensive to insert, update or
delete records.